# Python: Iterating through a directory and writing the results separate txt files

Tags: python, loops, pdf, glob, python-tesseract

I'm trying to iterate through a directory of pdf files. I first convert all the PDFs to jpeg and finally to txt. I've been able to iterate through the directory of PDFs and write each jpeg file to a single txt file, but what I really need is a separate txt file for each PDF. I understand the issue that each page of the pdf is being converted to a JPEG then written to the text file. If there are 2 PDFs, I would like 2 txt files. Below is my code so far. Thanks for your help.
from PIL import Image

```
import pytesseract 
import sys 
from pdf2image import convert_from_path 
import os 
import cv2
import glob

for filepath in glob.iglob("path/*.pdf"):
    PDF_file = filepath
  
    pages = convert_from_path(PDF_file, 500) 
  
    image_counter = 1
  
    for page in pages: 
  
        filename = "page_"+str(image_counter)+".jpg"
      
        page.save(filename, 'JPEG') 
  
        image_counter = image_counter + 1
  
    filelimit = image_counter-1
  
    outfile = "out_text.txt"
  
    f = open(outfile, "a") 
  
    for i in range(1, filelimit + 1): 
  
        filename = "page_"+str(i)+".jpg"
          
        text = str(((pytesseract.image_to_string(Image.open(filename))))) 
  
        text = text.replace('-\n', '')     
  
        f.write(text) 
  
    f.close()
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to have output in separate text files for different pages of pdfs. Then you should open the files as different names for every pdf's pages. Like this:

```
for i in range(1, filelimit + 1): 
    outfile = "out_text_"+ str(i) +".txt"
    f = open(outfile, "a") 
    filename = "page_"+str(i)+".jpg"
    text = str(((pytesseract.image_to_string(Image.open(filename))))) 
    text = text.replace('-\n', '')     
    f.write(text) 
    f.close()
```

Comment: Thanks. That's close to what I want, but not exactly. I don't want each page written to text, but if I have two PDFs for example, I would like two txt files. I understand that this might be difficult because each page of the PDF is actually being separated into JPEGs.